# How can I remove extraneous virtual directories from Exch 2016?

Tags: exchange-2016, virtual-directory

I am experimenting with setting up Exchange 2016 in a lab environment. Created a VM for DC and another for Exchange (both Server 2016). 
I ran in to some issues with the Exchange install and decided to recreate the Exchange VM (No changes to DC VM). Changed the name of the Exchange server from  EX.contoso.com  to  EXCH.contoso.com .

The next install went perfectly , but now I have virtual directories for both EX. and EXCH (OWA/ECP/autodiscover, etc,). Power shell commands to remove the directories fail because of the name change(tried Remove-*VirtualDirectory). I get the "check that the server exists" error.
    I checked IIS but can't seem to find the extra directories listed. I can see the directories when I log in to ECP.
    Is there another way to remove the extra directories??

Answer (score 0):

These extra directories should be the residual information of the EX server, we can delete the EX server via ADSI Edit tool and check if any helps:

Expand Configuration, CN=Configuration, CN=Services, CN=Microsoft Exchange, CN=, CN=Administrative Groups, CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOH…, CN=Servers, select the server, and right-click on it and click Delete

[image]